# Why is /run/systemd/resolved.conf.d/isc-dhcp-v4-eno1.conf wrong?

Tags: dns, dhclient

Yesterday i updated  Ubuntu 18.10, but after poweroff/poweron the DNS was wrong, so that routing worked, e. g. ping 8.8.8.8, but not name resolving.
So i overwrote the resolving files, e. g. /etc/resolv.conf, but that was not enough. I also had to overwrite /run/systemd/resolved.conf.d/isc-dhcp-v4-eno1.conf, because the file had

DNS=192.168.0.1

which ist wrong because that is the default gateway, not a DNS server!
Today, and without rebooting, the problem was back again; the process, dhclient -1 eno1, wrote the wrong value for the DNS server into /run/systemd/resolved.conf.d/isc-dhcp-v4-eno1.conf !
So as a workaround i am using:

```
# Workaround for the Bug that DHCP (dhclient -1 eno1) tries to use the Default-GW as a DNS server, under Ubuntu 18.10 and since 2018-11-18:
cp /root/bin/isc-dhcp-v4-eno1.conf /run/systemd/resolved.conf.d/isc-dhcp-v4-eno1.conf
systemctl restart systemd-resolved.service
```

in a Bash script which is called every half hour via /etc/crontab.
Is the a better solution for this Bug?

With Windows 8.1 the name resolving still works without problems.